# Partial data getting sqooped using Sqoop

Tags: hadoop, teradata, sqoop

I am trying to sqoop a Teradata table with 5 billion rows and only 2.35 billion rows of data is getting sqooped.
The job is getting completed successfully without any issues, I am using TeradataConnManager with 36 mappers , can someone provide any pointers on what might be the issue. It is a simple table import into a HDFS directory.

Comment: can you provide some code? can you try to run your sqoop job on small test sample of data?

Comment: I am not seeing any issues with small data --- used statement is  "sqoop import -Dmapred.job.queue.name=xxxxxx -libjars /usr/hdp/current/sqoop-client/lib/ \
 --connect jdbc:teradata://xxxxxxx/Database=xxxxxxx \
 --connection-manager org.apache.sqoop.teradata.TeradataConnManager \
 --username xxxxxxxxxx \
 --password xxxxxxxxxx  \
 --table xxxxxxxxxxxxx \
 --fields-terminated-by '\001' \
 --num-mappers 36 \
 --split-by xxxxxxx \
 --target-dir  "/xxx/xxx/xxx/xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx" "